# Maximum variance

Tags: probability, analysis, calculus-of-variations

Consider a random variable $X$ with continuous probability density $f(x)$ and compact support, say $[a,b]$ with $a<b$.
Moreover, let $f(x)$ vanish at the boundary, i.e.  $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.

Question:

What is the maximum variance which such a random variable can take?

EDIT:

It should have been mentioned here, that this problem is already solved in literature for probability densities without any further restrictions and the solution is given by a disrete (non-continuous) probability with weight 1/2 at the boundary. See comments and the "duplicate-link". However, I'm asking for a **continuous probability density** instead, which is **zero at the boundary**.

With these two additionnal conditions, the question is completely different. Maybe, a solution does not exist. Then, maybe there is a sequence of continuous probability densities $f_n(x)$, $n=1,2,3...$, whose limes has maximum variance. But I don't know how to construct such a sequence which gets peaked at the boundary.

Comment: Are you sure the maximum is attainable under the regularity conditions on $f$ you're asking for?  Or are you just looking for the supremum over all distributions satisfying your conditions.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna No, I'm not sure.

Comment: Absent the continuity and boundary conditions, we'd want probability $\frac 12$ at each endpoint.  Adding the boundary, we'd move the two atoms to $a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon$.  Adding continuity, we'd just round these atoms to a bimodal.  But all these modifications can be done with arbitrarily small changes to the variance.

Comment: @lulu  is correct here; I suspect 'maximum' is just a slip of rigor rather than a critical component of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution have a mean value $\mu$ and variance $S^2$, given the compact support $r=[a,b]$, the Popoviciu inequality states:
$$S^2\le\dfrac{r^2}{4}$$ while the Bathia - Davies bound is:
$$S^2\le (b-\mu)(\mu-a)$$

Comment: Surely that inequality is strict here because equality will correspond to point-masses at $a$ and $b$ which violate kaffeeauf's conditions.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna: Ok. In this case you can take into account only the first bound

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: For which $f(x)$ does the equal sign hold in case of the first bound?